# How to make a deep copy of an NSDictionary, the easy way?

Tags: iphone

How to make a deep copy of an NSDictionary, the easy way? In particular, it's an NSUserDefaults dictionary that contains only property list objects, so objects which are serializable.

Would I just iterate over it and build a complete new one with copied values? Guess you guys have a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
newDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:oldDict copyItems:YES];
```

Comment: I don't think this is a deep copy

Comment: This is not a deep copy, it performs a shallow copy.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Tried to delete my answer, but can't because it has been accepted.

Comment: This is correct, look at Apple's docs on 
- initWithDictionary:copyItems:

Comment: "If YES, each object in otherDictionary receives a copyWithZone: message to create a copy of the object—objects must conform to the NSCopying protocol."